# cannot return corecct value of sum, prime number in matrix array

Tags: java, arrays, primes

so i try to make a sum from the matrix, that all prime number add to the variable sum. this is my code, i cannot understand why in the else statement its not going well.

```
    public static void checkPrimeAVG2DArray() {

    int arr[] [] = {{5, 4, 6}, {11, 15, 9}, {14, 7, 3}};
    double avg = checkPrimeAVG2DArray (arr);
    System.out.println("avg : " + avg); // i revive 176, why?
}
public static double checkPrimeAVG2DArray(int[][] arr) {
    int sum =0;

    for (int i=0; i< arr.length; i++ ) {
        for (int j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {



            for (int temp=2; temp < arr[i][j]; temp++ ) {
                if ( arr[i][j] % temp == 0) {
                    temp++;
                    System.out.println(arr[i][j] + " is not prime number");
                    break;

            } else {
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            }
    }
    }}
    return sum;
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not going well"?

Comment: When asking for free help please take the time to correctly format and indent your code. Also, we have no idea what is actually going wrong - you will need to describe the exact issue much better.

Comment: Run your code using your debugger, line by line. Or run it on paper, line by line. Note that your incorrect indentation gives you a false structure. Fix it, and you might see the problem immediately. Naming a method that is supposed to sum prime numbers "checkPrimeAVG2DArray" is also very confusing. How about `sumPrimeNumbers`?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to calculate an average (based on your naming) but all you did was add things up - you will have to divide somewhere in the process...

Comment: OK sory.
so, i try to take all the prime numbers and put this in the variable sum.
the curect value need to be 26.

this is what going on in the debugger.
5 10 15 26 37 48  59 70  81 92 103 114 129

Comment: OK. Have you run the code step by step using your debugger? Or on paper? Have you indented your code correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things by extracting your prime logic into a seperate method and then calling it for each value in the 2D array.

```
    public static double checkPrimeAVG2DArray(int[][] arr) {
        int sum =0;
        double numberOfPrimesInArray = 0.0;
        for (int i=0; i< arr.length; i++ )
        {
            for (int j=0; j<arr.length; j++)
            {
                if(checkNumberIsPrime(arr[i][j]))
                {
                    numberOfPrimesInArray++;
                    sum += arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return sum/numberOfPrimesInArray;
    }

  public static boolean checkNumberIsPrime(int valueToCheck)
  {
      int temp;
      for(int i=2;i<=valueToCheck/2;i++)
        {
           temp=valueToCheck%i;
           if(temp==0)
           {
              return false;
           }
        }

      return true;
  }
```